# Android studio 'Clipart' option not showing anything on clicking

Tags: android, xml, image, android-studio, drawable

I need to use clipart in vector asset and image asset option in drawable folder but when I click on clipart to choose different images it does not do anything . It just shows a blue boundary around the last clipart which I used (Screenshot of it is in the below link).I am using android for a long time but this didn't happen before. If anyone had this issue before and know how to solve it please do share how.

Link of the image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/V75oy.png

Comment: Did you try to invalidate caches and restart?

Comment: Yes, I did. It didn't work either. Do you know some other method to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Deleting or renaming icons folder in sdk folder works for me (default folder is located in %username%/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/icons as Ken's Answer above).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33545826)

Comment: Thank you this works! In MacOS the folder is '~.Library/Android/sdk/icons'

Answer (score 0):

I've spent approx. 6 hours for reinstalling Android Studio, deleting gradle files, and trying older versions of Android Studio. But none of them hasn't worked. Finally, I found the solution: the error isn't in Android Studio but in SDK.

- **Delete All your SDK files** and download them again. This will help :)

Comment: All you have to do is rename or delete the icons folder. In Windows it's AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/icons. Afterwards, re-launch Studio, try the clip art button again and it should be working again.