# Clip Art from Configure Vector Asset window in Android Studio is not working

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, vector, icons

I need to use default vector icons but after clicking on the "clip Art" option, there is nothing happening, I am unable to select any vector image from the Android assets.

[image]

Comment: it is solved, actually, i have to update my SDK and it is resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to update the sdk. Just simply delete or rename icon folder in sdk folder as I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74988634/7094089). By default, sdk folder is located in %username%/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/icons. Just rename or delete it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33546082)

Comment: The change of name resolved the issue already. Thanks